# Selection of elements based on other elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :students
end

class Class <ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :students
end

class Student <ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :teacher
   belongs_to :class
end
```

I want to create a list of teachers, and below their names: table with  classes from which this teacher has students and number of this students. More or less something like this:

```
Teacher XYZ:
Class 1A  |  3 students
Class 3D | 2 students
```

How can I check if teacher has students from each class and later count only the students that belongs to both this particular teacher and class?

Comment: Shouldn't a teacher have many classes? Then you can just eager load the classes for that teacher

Comment: Sadly no. Teacher doesn't alwyas teach whole class. There are cases in which he teaches just a few students from class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It isn't necessary to apologize for learning a language; Write well thought-out questions and we're happy to help you. Stick to the point as you write to help us more quickly read your question. As for tagging questions, stick to tags that have a large number of followers. "selection" is worthless as evidenced by 7 followers. "has-many" is even worse, with only 2 followers. "ActiveRecord" would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a query to eager load the classes and students:

```
@teachers = Teacher.includes(students: :class)
```

Then I would use `group_by` in the view to group the students by the class.

```
<% @teachers.each do |teacher| %>
  <%= teacher.name %>
  <% teacher.students.group_by(&:class).each do |class, students| %>
    <%= class.name %> | <%= students.size %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I've assumed that a teacher and a class both have a name. There may well be a better way using something like has_many through but I can't see it at the moment.

On another note you shouldn't name your object `Class` it's going to cause you a lot of problems I'd have thought because it's defined in ruby already http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Class.html.  I'd call it something like SchoolClass to avoid conflicts.

Comment: It works exactly like I wanted, thank you very much! Also, thank you for this advice about Class. You're right, SchoolClass would be much better.